# Azure search indexer failing with error message

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

My azure search indexer which reads from an sql table with Change Tracking, is failing with the following error

```
"Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'System.String'."
```

If I reset the indexer, it'll start working fine. What is the root cause of the problem here?

Comment: Hi Harry, please email me your service name, region, and indexer name and we'll take a look. eugenesh at the usual Microsoft domain. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We’ve identified an issue in SQL indexers that use SQL integrated change detection that affects a very small number of customers. We’re working on a fix, which will probably be deployed in production next week. We'll also improve our telemetry so that we'll be able to identify this class of issues proactively.

The workaround you’ve already used (resetting the indexer) is the best workaround for this issue.

Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: Thanks a lot, for you prompt response. You guys at Azure Search Rock!